# Execl in C with gzip

Tags: c, gzip

I have to gzip a file into a path. What i want to do is this:

```
gzip -9c example.txt > /home/paulo/new_name
```

If i do this by and it works perfectly fine, but i am using a execlp to execute this in c:

```
  execlp("gzip","gzip","-9c",file,">",path,NULL);
```

But when i use this execlp i get random characters on stdout. I just printed file and path to check if both were right:

```
 printf("%s, %s\n",file,path);
```

And i got this:

```
example.txt, /home/paulo/new_name
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The shell redirection command ">" is not an *argument to `execlp`* and is most likely your error.

Comment: Redirection like you attempt is a feature of some *shells*. It's not something that `exec` does. If you want to `exec` your own processes, you need to reopen stdout yourself.

Comment: Is there a way of compress a file into a path and keep the original file without using redirection?

Comment: Did you try reading the manual page for gzip? `man gzip`

Comment: Run: `man gzip`. Then press `/` to search. Write `keep` and press `Enter`.  Write `/` and press `Enter` to navigate to another match. Good luck.

Comment: gzip -k does what i want, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to invoke the shell:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "gzip -9c example.txt > /home/paulo/new_name", NULL);
```

That is similar to what the `system` function does. So another option is:

```
exit(system("gzip -9c example.txt > /home/paulo/new_name"));
```